# How to stop cardview overlapping on android lollipop and above

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

i made an app to read data from json in recycler view. when i run the app on an android 4.4 it looks like this [IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UeXAh.png) but when i run it on an android 5.0 or above it looks like this [IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dbCH.png)

here is the code for the card view layout

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:cardview="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    app:cardElevation="5dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="0.5dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    android:layout_margin="1dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/date"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="123"
            android:textColor="#565656"
            android:textSize="9dp" />


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/comment"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/thumbnail" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="12dp"
            android:layout_height="12dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/comment" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:textColor="#3f51b4"
            android:text="NEWS"
            android:textSize="8dp"
            android:id="@+id/categories"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="69dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:background="#919191"
            android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLines="3"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:text="MMM is now back in buisness so if your money dy dia better go collect am no"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#222"
            android:textSize="12dp"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/thumbnail"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/thumbnail" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/excerpt"
            android:maxLines="3"
            android:textSize="7dp"
            android:text="if your money dy dia go collect am nw o"
            android:layout_below="@+id/title"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/comment" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

any help please?

Comment: Overlapping ? Where ? the image looks good to me. Is the image provided correct ?

Comment: updated @RakshitNawani

Comment: make the android:layout_height to wrap_content and give a margin according to your need and they try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change your app namespace declaration from:

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

to:

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

See will that help because you already using `app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"`
and that should make space between cards in android 5.0. Also add `app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"`

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But this solution includes extra margin around the cardview. So I had to adjust the margin of Parent view accordingly.